# Filter list of files to those that exist

Tags: bash, file

How do I filter a list of files to the ones that exist?

For example,

```
echo 'a.txt
does/not.exist
b.txt' | <???>
```

would print

```
a.txt
b.txt
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can `ls -d` the files and see which ones get some output. Since you have those in a string, just pipe the list and use `xargs` to be able to `ls` them.

To hide errors, redirect those to `/dev/null`. All together, `xargs ls -d 2>/dev/null` makes it:

```
$ echo 'a.txt
b.txt
other' | xargs ls -d 2>/dev/null
a.txt
b.txt
```

As you see, `xargs ls -d` executes `ls -d` to all the arguments given. `2>/dev/null` gets rid of the stderr messages.

Comment: ... with the usual caveats about parsing `ls` output; for example, if one of the arguments is a directory, you will get the directory's contents, not its name.

Comment: Good one, maybe `ls -d` would be best.

Comment: On Ubuntu, `echo "" | (xargs ls -d 2>/dev/null)` appears to result in `.` in the output, which seems to be because `ls -d` results in `.`.

Comment: This appears to be corrected by unconditionally prepending a newline: `echo "" | (echo "\n" && cat) | (xargs ls -d 2>/dev/null)`. Think of the first echo as the command that might result in a blank line.

Comment: Nicely done; may be worth adding `-1` to ensure line-by-line output, and `-f` to prevent the input paths from getting _sorted_ (though you may actually prefer that). Also, note that filenames with _embedded spaces_ won't be handled correctly.

Comment: Downvoted for relying on vagueness like "some output". I don't believe this is reliable.

Answer (score 7):

If you have ***GNU* `xargs`**, use `-d '\n'` to ensure that **filenames (including directories) with *embedded spaces* are handled correctly**, by splitting the input into *whole lines* rather than also by intra-line whitespace.

```
echo 'a.txt
does/not.exist
b.txt' | xargs -d '\n' ls -1df 2>/dev/null
```

Note:

- The `ls` command emits an error for each non-existent input path, which `2>/dev/null` ignores, while echoing existing paths as-is.
- Option `-1` prints each path on its own line, `-d` prevents recursing into directories, and `-f` prevents *sorting* of the input paths (if you actually *want* sorting, omit the `f`).

---

On **macOS/BSD, `xargs`** doesn't support `-d`, which requires a workaround via NUL-separated input using `tr` and `xargs`'s `-0` option:

```
echo 'a.txt
does/not.exist
b.txt' | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 ls -1df 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 5):

As a one-liner, and pure bash for speed (improved from mklement0's answer, would have commented if I'd had the rep):

```
{ ls; echo does/not.exist; } | while IFS= read -r f; do [[ -f "$f" ]] && echo "$f"; done
```

Comment: Nice, though you probably meant [rjmunro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48944591/45375). As for a speed advantage: for a small number of input lines this will probably perform better than an external-utility-based solution, but with a large number of input lines the latter is likely faster. The tradeoff is cost of child-process creation vs. slow shell-code loops.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I came up with, use `stats`'s exit code in a while read loop:

```
<input> | while IFS= read -r f; do stat "$f" &>/dev/null && echo "$f"; done
```

Note that this solution is *slow*, because it loops in shell code, and calls an
external utility (creates a child process, `stat`) in every iteration.

Comment: if you replace `stat "$f" &&` with `if ! [[ -e "$f" || -h "$f" ]]; then`, this becomes a pretty thin wrapper on C-level code. I'd expect it to be pretty darn fast, actually.

Answer (score 1):

I would use bash's if to check for the files. It ends up a bit less compact, but I think it's clearer to read, and easier to do something with each found file in the results.

It is compatible with filenames with spaces.

```
echo 'a.txt
does/not.exist
b.txt' | while read filename
do
  if [[ -f "$filename" ]]
  then
    echo $filename # Or do something else with the files here
  fi
done
```

Comment: Nice, though `while IFS= read -r filename` would make it more robust (proper handling of filenames with spaces, no accidental interpretation of escape sequences).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to pass multiple files to `stat`, and if the file doesn't exist it will just print a message to STDERR. So you can do this:

```
<input> | xargs stat --printf '%n\n' 2> /dev/null
```

Or if you are using null-terminated paths (which I recommend and is not possible with `ls`):

```
<input> | xargs -0 stat --printf '%n\0' 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the only solution that properly works on an empty input.