# Filter a list of files in bash if a corresponding file is found

Tags: bash, git, grep

I have a bunch of `.js` files. Since have corresponding `.spec.js` some have `.test.js` files and some have no corresponding files.

I am converting the spec files to test files, but I want to target the files that are most often changed first.

To do that I have a bash command that is [Finding most changed files in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686582/finding-most-changed-files-in-git) but I want to filter the returned list to only include files that have a matching `.spec.js` file.

Here is the existing command:

```
git log --pretty=format: --name-only | sort | uniq -c | sort -rg | head -10
```

The code from the question asking to [List files missing a corresponding file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36850722/list-files-missing-a-corresponding-file) looks helpful

```bash
for f in *.ext; do test -e $f.txt || echo $f; done
```

Means I could use

```bash
for f in $(git log --pretty=format: --name-only); do test -e ${f%.*}.spec.js && echo $f; done | sort | uniq -c | sort -rg | head -25
```

But I don't want to loop over every line of my git log output if possible, because it obviously contains duplicates! It's quite quick (~1 sec) but I feel like there should be a 'neater' option.

The answers at [Filter list of files to those that exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119035/filter-list-of-files-to-those-that-exist) almost help but relies on `ls`.

Is there a better way to get this output?

Comment: move the `sort|uniq|sort|head` inside to `$(git ... |sort|uniq|sort|head)`?

Comment: Couldn't you use grep to only include files that have a matching .spec.js file?

Comment: @markp-fuso but then I need to a) remove my count from the regex, and b) account for whether the top 25 don't have a corresponding `.spec.js` file

Comment: @Robin how would you do that?

Comment: *Git* doesn't have the power to do what you want with a pathspec: either it matches `*.js` or it matches `*.spec.js` based on whichever pathspec you list, and `git log` will list the commit if any path matches any pathspec (ie you always get boolean-"or"-behavior). To cut down on the number of lines listed for the rest of the pipeline to work on, use whichever of `*.js` or `*.spec.js` occurs less frequently. But you'll need even more footwork to make use of this.

Comment: You might, for instance, end up using `git rev-list HEAD --full-history -- '*.js' | git log --no-walk --stdin --pretty=format: --name-only -- '*.js' '*.spec.js'`. That way you get blank-line-separated lists of just js and spec.js files.

Comment: You then need to decide whether to look at the files *in the commit in question* (for which you'll need its hash ID), or just in the *current working tree* as you're doing now.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly something like this:
`while IFS= read -r file; do echo $file done < <(git log --pretty-format: --name-only | grep ".spec.js" | sort | uniq -c | sort -rg | head -25)` 
This is one way you could use grep to filter your git log result. Then you can do whatever you want in the while loop. This was tested. Make sure you have no space between these <(

Comment: Thanks for posting, can you show how you combine it with the git command?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage OK, I just combined the solution with the git command. It works fine.